# Redis pipeline returns empty list

Tags: python, redis, pipeline

I am trying to use python redis client to make redis pipeline to call a redis server for some data. This data may exist or not. Even if the data is not existing, I am supposed to receive something like `[None, [None]]` according what I have read and experimented with python redis client.

However, there are sometimes that I get a empty list back, something like [], which caused exceptions in following (I AM MISSING!) code when I try to parse the returned result list. Moreover, when I retry the same requests manually after I found the issue I cannot reproduce the same problem, the reids server returns me with the correct data or [None, [None]], which is handled by me code.

There is no data written or data change to the redis server at all, only read in my code.

Is there anyone has any idea about what cause this to happen? Since from the logic, this should not happen at all.

By the way, I am using python redis client 2.10.3

Any insight will help. Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably that you did something like this:

```
pipe.watch(...)
...
pipe.execute()
```

without calling `pipe.multi()`

```
   # after WATCHing, the pipeline is put into immediate execution
   # mode until we tell it to start buffering commands again.
```

see [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#pipelines)